# Login with OTP/2FA using PHP MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It is working fine except

if I put a number on "otp" field, it goes to home.php even though it does not match the number on the database.

Would you please tell me what is wrong or missing the code?

Thank you!

```
if(!empty($_POST["authenticate"]) && $_POST["otp"]!='') {
    
    try {
        $otp_code = $_POST["otp"];
        
        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table4 WHERE otp=:otp_code AND expired!=1 AND NOW() <= DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)");
            
        $statement->bindParam(":otp_code", $otp_code);
            
        $statement->execute();
        $count=$statement->rowCount();
        if($count<1)
            {
            
            $data = [
                'expired' => 1,
                'otp_code' => $otp_code,
            ];
            
            $sql = "UPDATE $table4 SET expired=:expired WHERE otp=:otp_code";
            $stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute($data);
            
            $_SESSION['otp_code'] = $otp_code;
            
            header("Location: home.php");
        
        } else {
            $errorMessage = "Invalid Security Code!";
        }
        
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error : Check your error message.";
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
    
} else if (!empty($_POST["otp"])) {
    $errorMessage = "Enter Security Code!"; 
}
```

Comment: You have `if ($count < 1)` ... so, if zero rows are found, you're going to update the row and redirect.

Comment: Note, if your OTP code is a long token like a UUID or SHA hash, this is ok. However, if your code is something short like a six digit number, then you're going to want to also have `WHERE user = :user` on your where clause. (Unless you've already got a unique constraint on that column in the database.) Otherwise, you run the risk of two users having the same code at the same time.

Comment: Also, you should probably change your update so that it explicitly verifies the OTP hasn't already been used, e.g., `WHERE otp=:otp_code AND expired = 0` and then check the result of the query to make sure it changed exactly one row. Otherwise, you could have two separate sessions "use" the token at the same time.

Comment: Alex. Thank you for your reply.
I changed to ```  if ( !empty($count)) {`
and ` WHERE otp=:otp_code AND expired=0 ``` 
I tried to put any number on the database and not on the database, I received the error message "Invalid Security Code!". so I removed ```   AND NOW() <= DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) ```  then it's working fine. But now I have another issue.

Comment: Well obvious test there is to do `SELECT NOW()` and `SELECT DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)` in your SQL shell and see what you get.

Comment: I changed to ``` AND NOW() <= DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR) ``` then it's working fine. Is there any way to only update within 10 minutes of the current time on the created instead of 8 hours? Thank you!